# Asp.net simple membership. change password failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am using simple membership in my application. I have changed datatype of userId from int to bigint and accordingly changed datatype in all referenced field of userId.
Create user, edit user functionality are working fine. but when we do change password, getting following error.

> "implicit convert long to int? not possible"

My code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     bool resetResponse = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ReturnToken.ToString(), model.Password.ToString());
     if (resetResponse)
     {
         ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Changed";
     }
     else
     {
         ViewBag.Message = "Something went horribly wrong!";
     }
}
```

Please let me know what is the problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show your work?

Comment: How is the database created? Is it code first approach?

Comment: yes it is code first.

Comment: have you tried enabling migration and then updating your database?

Comment: How did you modify the entities for the other tables used by SimpleMembership?  As far as I know they are not accessible for change. The password is stored in a separate table from the UserProfile and my guess is that the foreign key is still an int. You will have to show more of your work to get a useful answer for this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration UserIdTypeChange ' or whatever you want to name it'     
update database
```

in

> Package manager console

which can be found in

> Tools-> Library package manager ->